# Center position fixed horizontally

Tags: html, css

I want to dynamically append to the end of the `body` a fixed-positioned to the bottom box that has 1000px width and is centered horizontally.

When I create it with percentage width I can easily add margins and everything is ok, but when I have it in pixels I can't add margins anymore (it has to be responsive). `auto` doesn't work either.

How can I do that?

```
<div style="position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 1000px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0;height: 100px; background-color: green;">
</div>
```

Comment: Show us a not-working demo.

Comment: Provide some code please

Comment: Sure, I provided some code, it has to be appended to the end of the body tag, while I don't know what css will other elements on the website have.

Comment: @Karol show what you have tried

Comment: you used the word "dynamically" but didn't provide any JS code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/eesry2ss/

```css
body:after {
    content:"";
    width: 1000px;
    height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    bottom:0;
    margin-left: -500px;
    background-color:green;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this also:

```
div{
  position: fixed; 
  bottom: 0; 
  width: 1000px; 
  left: 50%;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
  height: 100px; 
  background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```css
div{
  position: fixed; 
  bottom: 0; 
  width: 1000px; 
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -500px;
  height: 100px; 
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
 
</div>
```

Comment: As per your latest edit, if you just want to append to end of the body tag, you don't need a div. You can achieve it using the pseudo selector :after. In that case, change div for body:after on the css above.

Answer (score 0):

Try CSS3, to avoid giving calculated values in pixel for your margins.

```
left:50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

Here's a demo: https://jsbin.com/zejutisabo/edit?html,css,output