# prevent Vertical scroll but allow Horizontal scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I currently have a small agenda with a dayview

when my dynamic table starts to have a lot of `<td>`'s, a horizontal scrollbar apears but when the user scrolls to the right, he no longer has visual on what time he's actually selecting. I've created a small example shown in the snippet.

```css
#container{
  width: 400px;
  height:250px;
  border:1px solid black;
  overflow-x:auto;
  white-space:nowrap;
  position:relative;
}

table{
  border:1px solid black;
  border-collapse:collapse;
}


table th{
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin:0;
  display:block;
}

table td{
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  min-width: 150px;
  min-height: 18px;
  display:inline-block;
}

table tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}
table tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.secondTable{
  border-left: none !important;
}

.firstTableCon{
  margin-left:100px;
  margin-top:50px;
  position:relative;
  
}

.tableContainer{
  display:inline-block;
}

#absoluteContainer{
  /* position:absolute; */
}

#timeTable{
  /* position:fixed; */
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="tableContainer firstTableCon">
    <div id="absoluteContainer">
      <table id="timeTable">
        <tr>
          <th>
            8:00
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>
            9:00
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>
            10:00
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>
            11:00
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>
            12:00
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>
            13:00
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>
            14:00
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th style="border:0px;">
            15:00
          </th>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tableContainer">
    <table class="secondTable">
      <tr>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td style="border:0px;">

        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

</div>
```

I'd like the table that shows what time you're selecting (a vertical table) to scroll with the screen to the right, but maintain position when scrolling up or down.

preferable a css solution but if Javascript is the only option I'd be forced to use that.

**Before this gets flagged as duplicate, I've seen the other question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33913339/center-position-fixed-horizontally) and tried the fiddles BUT they did not work in the way I wanted**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, you may need to use `position: sticky` with `left: 0` on `.firstTableCon`:

```css
#container{
  width: 400px;
  height:250px;
  border:1px solid black;
  overflow-x:auto;
  white-space:nowrap;
  position:relative;
}

table{
  border:1px solid black;
  border-collapse:collapse;
}


table th{
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin:0;
  display:block;
}

table td{
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  min-width: 150px;
  min-height: 18px;
  display:inline-block;
}

table tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}
table tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.secondTable{
  border-left: none !important;
}

.firstTableCon{
  margin-left:100px;
  margin-top:50px;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
}

.tableContainer{
  display:inline-block;
}

#absoluteContainer{
  /* position:absolute; */
}

#timeTable{
  /* position:fixed; */
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="tableContainer firstTableCon">
    <div id="absoluteContainer">
      <table id="timeTable">
        <tr>
          <th>
            8:00
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>
            9:00
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>
            10:00
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>
            11:00
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>
            12:00
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>
            13:00
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>
            14:00
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th style="border:0px;">
            15:00
          </th>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tableContainer">
    <table class="secondTable">
      <tr>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td style="border:0px;">

        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: finally someone who understands haha

Comment: can you share your fiddle?

Comment: oh wait I think I see, you removed position:relative; from .tableContainer

Comment: yeah I got my fiddle to work now. :) https://jsfiddle.net/d3gcfhny/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can add overflow-y:hidden; in container

```css
#container{
  width: 400px;
  height:250px;
  border:1px solid black;
  overflow-x:auto;
  white-space:nowrap;
  position:relative;
  overflow-y:hidden;
}

table{
  border:1px solid black;
  border-collapse:collapse;
}


table th{
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin:0;
  display:block;
}

table td{
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  min-width: 150px;
  min-height: 18px;
  display:inline-block;
}

table tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}
table tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.secondTable{
  border-left: none !important;
}

.firstTableCon{
  margin-left:100px;
  margin-top:50px;
  position:relative;
  
}

.tableContainer{
  display:inline-block;
}

#absoluteContainer{
  /* position:absolute; */
}

#timeTable{
  /* position:fixed; */
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="tableContainer firstTableCon">
    <div id="absoluteContainer">
      <table id="timeTable">
        <tr>
          <th>
            8:00
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>
            9:00
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>
            10:00
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>
            11:00
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>
            12:00
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>
            13:00
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>
            14:00
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th style="border:0px;">
            15:00
          </th>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tableContainer">
    <table class="secondTable">
      <tr>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td style="border:0px;">

        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

</div>
```